# How do you make a virtual table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

In SQLite it is possible to make virtual tables based on things outside the database, as described in this article:

http://www.drdobbs.com/database/query-anything-with-sqlite/202802959

That's great, but I like the PostgreSQL command line client better than the one for SQLite. So, how can I make virtual tables in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want "foreign data wrappers" (often abbreviated "fdw"). There are a couple included in the core postgresql distribution: [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html), which allows you to create a table interface to files local to the DB, and [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html), which allows you to interface with other postgresql databases.

There are [a number of community-written fdws](http://pgxn.org/tag/fdw/), as well, for interacting with things like couchdb, mysql, or even amazon s3.

Comment: I didn't see a SQLite fdw in the list, but found one here: https://github.com/gleu/sqlite_fdw.